# Centralize before and after actions around a new task created by TPL

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, busyindicator

In our application ,we use TPL to create tasks whenever we would want to make a service call.We have a busy indicator which is set to true whenever a task is started and cleared whenever the task  is completed or faulted.Is there any way to accomplish this in a generic way instead of doing this for every single task created ?

First instance :

```
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = true;
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.BusyMessage = "Loading...";

        var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoTask1());
        task1.ContinueWith(antecdent =>
        {
            ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = false;
            CustomAction1();
        }
```

Second Instance :

```
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = true;
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.BusyMessage = "Loading...";

        var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoTask2());
        task2.ContinueWith(antecdent =>
        {
            ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = false;
            CustomAction2();
        }
```

the same is  logic is repeated all through the application whenever a service call is made is there any way to avoid this repetition ?

For example there is a dragstarted and dragcompleted events which get fired for all drag operations , so it possible to have taskstarted and taskcompleted event possibly by extending the task factory or otherwise ?

Edit : Made changes so that the question is more clear.You can now observe that steps before starting and ending a task is same but different functions needs to be executed for each task when it runs to completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It appears I've misunderstood the question.  Creating this "start, wait, continue" as a centralized function is a good move, and could be created like this:

```
public void DoIt(Action ThingToDo) {
    ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = true;
    ComponentViewModel.Instance.BusyMessage = "Loading...";

    var loadProviderTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(ThingToDo);
    loadProviderTask.ContinueWith(antecdent =>
    {
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,Sorry as my question was not clear.I have edited the question.I want different functions to be executed after task completion

Comment: @VasudevanKannan, then just pass it as another delegate argument to the function and invoke it in the continuation.

Comment: @robrich, did you mean `Task.Factory.StartNew(ThingToDo)`? Also, the usual naming convention in .Net is to start parameters with a lowercase letter.

Comment: public static Task DoTaskWithBusyIndicator(Action thingToDo,Action completionTask) {
    ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = true;
    ComponentViewModel.Instance.BusyMessage = "Loading...";

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Action);
    task.ContinueWith(antecdent =>
    {
        ComponentViewModel.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = false;
  completionTask();
    }
 return task;
}

Comment: @svick,I made some minor changes and posted a comment.Any one still interested in the idea of creating taskstarted and taskcompleted event as this solution involves creating multiple overloads and can become quite complex with the taskcreationoptions and taskcontinuationoptions etc

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I've edited to be Task.Factory.StartNew(ThingToDo)